# What is the mime-type for All Files

Tags: c++, qt, mime-types

Simple Question: What is the mimetype for "All Files", i.e. `*` or `*.*`

I need it to add the option "All Files" to a filter for files in the `QFileDialog`:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
QStringList mTypes= byteToStringList(QImageReader::supportedMimeTypes());
mTypes.append("???");//what to add here to get "All Files (*)" or "All Files (*.*)"
dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(mTypes);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it's literally in [the documentation for the function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setMimeTypeFilters)

says

> Use "application/octet-stream" for the "All files (*)" filter, since that is the base MIME type for all files.

Comment: You forgot about folders which have mime type `inode/directory`

Answer (score 1):

Just don't set any mime type filter at all, then it will show all files.

Comment: he presumably wants a dropdown field in the dialog to filter on individual known types too

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
```